# Is it possible to set column width in SQLite table?

Tags: android, database, string, sqlite

I am trying to display a SQLite table in a view.  I want my first column to have a width of 20 characters.  I have attempted to achieve this effect by using the substring method but I get stringindexoutofboundsexceptions with strings less than 20 characters. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my code:

Method for displaying table in view:

```
public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_VALUE };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iQuantity = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUANTITY);
    int iValue = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VALUE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + /*c.getString(iRow) + " " +*/ c.getString(iName).substring(0, 20) + " " + c.getString(iQuantity) + " " + c.getString(iValue) + "\n";
    }
```

Comment: Is there any benefits for limiting the number of characters in a table field?

Comment: @LazyNinja Im displaying three columns and and i want to align the columns so it looks organized and leaves space for the next two columns.  My strings vary in range from 9 characters to 25 characters.

Comment: why do you have columns that waste 5 characters? You could also use [TextView#setEms()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEms%28int%29) / [TextView.html#setEllipsize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEllipsize%28android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29) to limit the text during displaying only

Comment: I dont know how your layout looks like , but a table layout could do the job. It is possible to do what you want, but I doubt it is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `c.getString(iName).substring(0, Math.min(20, c.getString(iName).length())` (possibly using a temporary for `c.getString(iName)`) instead of the substring you have now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want them then why select. You can just do

```
String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, "substr(" + KEY_NAME + ",1,20)", KEY_QUANTITY, KEY_VALUE };
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

and get at most 20 chars from the column.